# Is there any other way to execute SQL code periodically except cron?

Tags: php, sql, scripting, triggers

Basically I want to truncate a table every X days but I don't want to use cron. I would like to have a kind of built in script inside the php file to do this and maybe sql triggers can help me out. Unfortunately I don't know how to use them.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't use cron? It's probably the simplest and most obvious solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on the version of MySQL, you might have access to [CREATE EVENT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-event.html) which allows MySQL to trigger its own processes at scheduled times.

e.g.

```
CREATE EVENT myevent
    ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 DAY
    DO
      UPDATE myschema.mytable SET mycol = mycol + 1;
```

To run a task each day

Other databases may have equivalents, though you don't identify the database that you're using.

Comment: I'm using mysqli, does it apply to that?

Comment: Mysqli isn't the database, it's the interface between PHP and the MySQL database.... what it does mean though, is that you're using MySQL as your database, so yes! you can use it (just check on the version of MySQL that you're using first)

Comment: My mysql version is 5.5.8. Assuming it supports EVENTs, can it be done using the non-procedurial style, like this: $sql = "CREATE EVENT myevent
    ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 DAY
    DO
      UPDATE myschema.mytable SET mycol = mycol + 1"; $result = $connect->query($sql) or die(mysqli_error()); ?

Comment: MySQL 5.5.8 supports EVENTS, but don't do it using PHP, do it directly on the database

Comment: Well I'm afraid I'm becoming a nuisance but how can I do it directly on the database? By the way I have not such a broad knowledge of mysql. Thanks in advance. P.S: And im using phpmyadmin, by the way.

Comment: Never mind I sorted it out. I just put everything in the SQL tab in phpmyadmin interface. Thanks for the assistance. A well deserved right answer for you!

Answer (score 3):

You can build something that checks on each page visit when it was last emptied. If the last time was longer than you want, you empty it. It is not very efficient, but if you can't or don't want to use crons, this is a possibility.

Comment: I guess I'll have to work with timestamps in the database, right?

Answer (score 0):

On my sites, i have my own "cron" system. I make ajax request to my cron script right after the page has loaded. It checks current date against last cron date stored in database and if [current date - last cron date] is bigger than intercal given, excecute my cron script and update last cron date. I did it with ajax, so i can make quite heavy cron jobs and not affecting user page load. And also this cron excecutes only if users visit your pages and in many cases you do do not need to excecute cron if usesrs aren't visiting you page.